# PEP TryIt not showing policy WSO2IS

Tags: request, policy, pep, wso2-identity-server

If I am going to do a policy "try" within the pap the result on a request is correct.

After publishing the policy to a PDP the same request within the PEP Try it tool does not show any result. Is the PEP Tryit working correctly?

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes..  it is working correctly...  There can be few reasons for this..

1. PDP policy may not have been enabled.  Once you publish a policy , you want to enable it.. (In IS 450 and 460).
2. There can be more than one policy in the PDP.. . Therefore your request may be effected with them...
3. When there are more policies, You need to consider about policy combining algorithm and policy order as well

Please find detail on working on XACML with WSO2IS from [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/09/13/getting-start-with-wso2-identity-server-4-5-0/)

Comment: figured out the problem: If the policy was testet within the PAP the result got cached and even the policy wasnt enabeld it returend the correct reuslt within the PEP Try it tool. That was confusing :)